# FreeBSD,"setitimer" system call's source code

Tags: freebsd

I am doing a toy project. I want to find setitimer's source code. But after I tried "whereis" command, nothing came out.
Could you help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in [`sys/kern/kern_time.c`](http://svn.freebsd.org/viewvc/base/release/8.1.0/sys/kern/kern_time.c?revision=210188&view=markup) in the function `kern_setitimer`.

If you've got the kernel source installed on your system, the file is `/usr/src/sys/kern/kern_time.c`.

Comment: Wow!! You are my god! Thanks! I reallly wanna know, how can you find that?Could you please teach me the way to find system call's code? Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Andy Leman: Well, I have the kernel source code installed on my system in `/usr/src`. I used [`ack`](http://betterthangrep.com) to search for "setitimer", and found it in that file. Then I found the corresponding link on http://svn.freebsd.org.

Answer (score 1):

One good place to search kernel code is Robert Watson's [FreeBSD and Linux Kernel Cross-Reference](http://fxr.watson.org/), which is based on [LXR](http://lxr.sourceforge.net/). Search for identifier `setitimer` - find it [here](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/kern_time.c#L578).